# Suggest voting to close when downvoting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, vote-to-close, stackexchange-2.0

On [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) we've found that users will often downvote a question and complain about it being off topic, but not vote to close it.

I would like to see a popup when downvoting a question that says something like:

> Does this question really belong here?  If not, please vote to close.

Obviously this wouldn't make sense in established sites like SO so perhaps it should be tied to the lower vote threshold or even beta.

Comment: Shouldn't people know about closing by the time they have sufficient rep to use it? I know the limit is lower on the SE betas, but I would still expect people to be aware

Comment: This is a problem with 'User Education' imo, not with the system. Similar things happened on SO/SU not so long ago, but now it's nearly completely gone.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek it doesn't seem to be the case.  For an example see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65903/how-to-encourage-users-to-vote-to-close).

Answer (score 4):

Disagree.  If this were implemented, how long would it take before meta is flooded with complaints of over-zealous close voting like on SO?  Downvoting and close voting are separate concepts, and rightly so.

Comment: Agreed. Downvoting is completely different from voting to close.

Comment: This. If you don't understand when closing should be used, you shouldn't be voting to close. And we *definitely* don't want users to be associating closing and down-voting.