# How to encourage users to vote to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, stackexchange-2.0

On the Role-playing Game site we have a problem in that users will not vote to close a question, even if they they say it doesn't belong.

For example this question:

- [A Grimoire of Magic Item Curses and Boons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/a-grimoire-of-magic-item-curses-and-boons)

Has three downvotes, several comments saying it doesn't belong (from users over 500 rep), and only one vote to close.

It even has it's own [meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/521/what-do-you-think-about-a-grimoire-of-magic-item-curses-and-boons) where the consensus seems to be "this doesn't belong here".

And this is only one example of the trend on the site.

**How can we teach users to close things they don't want on the site?**

Comment: With the stigma given to closing by those that think duplicate or off topic questions are welcome just because the Stack Exchange system is TEH AWESOME!!11!!!, good luck.

Comment: @George Stocker the problem is people obviously don't think this question is welcome, far from it.  They just attack it in other ways, that unfortunately cause more drama.

Comment: See Also: [Suggest voting to close when downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65843/suggest-voting-to-close-when-downvoting) which was my first solution for this problem.

Comment: you're a mod there, set an example. Sooner or later they will learn about the difference between downvotes and vote-to-close. I guess the trouble is that many users at RPG.SE are not familiar with *any* SOFUE site... We should really feature-request a tutorial mode SE...

Comment: @Tobias I can't set an example particularly *because I am a mod*!  If I close something it automatically gets closed.  That teaches people that we'll come along and take care of it, not that they need to vote to close.

Comment: @CRoss: but they have to see *some* questions with a [closed] to start wondering "wtf does *that* mean?" at all when they haven't used SE before. Also as soon as beta-mode is over, i.e. the vote-to-close-rep-limit is raised, many users won't be able to close but should at least be encouraged to leave a comment and flag for a mod. Better than downvotes that have the wrong intention. However, I do get your point on [Suggest voting to close when downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65843/146482) now, that should be an option for beta sites at least

Comment: I count 38 users with enough rep to vote to close.  Are they familiar enough with the site to be comfortable with votes to close?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just chime in in the discussion on the meta, pointing out to people that closing to vote is the way forward? They might even tell you why they didn't. Either because they didn't know the possibility exists, or because they have not enough reputation, or...

One teacher once told me : "Repetitio mater studiorum est" - repetition is the mother of all learning. Apart from showing me why my mother nagged my ears off about everything, it really helped me in getting a point across. Repeat and repeat until they finally get it. As a mod, you have the possibility to do so on every meta-question that pops up regarding "questions that don't belong there"

good luck

Answer (score 1):

I assume many RPG.SE users are not familiar with the SE system and therefore simply don't know about closing questions - which is also less prominent in the UI than the downvote button. Maybe the admin-announcement at the top of the site (example at [gaming.SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com): [image: announce]
) could state something like

> Please familiarize yourself with [Closing questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question), which is *not* the same as downvoting