# Why isn't the community FAQ more prominent?

Tags: feature-request, support, meta-faq

[The official FAQ for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) (should perhaps be renamed to include SE-2.0?) is quite informative, but there is no prominent link anywhere at parent sites.

Why isn't it at least linked in the FAQ linked to at every single page? That only links to the respective meta's [faq]-tag despite the mentioned FAQ describing the most general questions about voting, closing, rep et al.

Answer (score 1):

Honest answer? Because I think the community FAQ as it exists today is an unreadable, un-navigable mess.

Comment: I disagree. It currently *is* the best source of information, e.g. in reply to [How to encourage users to vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65903/146482) the FAQ [What is a “closed” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/146482) seems to be the best answer on where to direct new SE users...

Comment: Granted there could be improvements made to presentation, making it easier to navigate and read, and I would welcome them. However in the absence of something better, it is the best we have right now.

Comment: Is this still the case? The community FAQ has a lot of information that site-specific FAQs don't have — although the same rules apply to the whole network. Could there be a **read more** link at the bottom of every site's FAQ-page pointing to the community FAQ?

Comment: @koiyu good idea, I think you could make a feature-request of that