# Could you add a link to the Community Faq to the faq?

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

I would like to risk asking the following question again:

**[Why isn't the community FAQ more prominent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65913)**

When this question was first answered by, @JeffAtwood, I understand that the [Community Faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) was more of a cacophonous mess.  In the past year the main page alone has had about 30 revisions (since Sept '10) and each of the linked questions tons more.  The main page has now, in total, been through 88? or 94? revisions.

That said, I've been a member for 14 months, and I found the Community Faq *today*.  Quite by accident in fact: I was about ask why the '/faq/' page doesn't have more questions... Coupled with: Where the heck is 'The FAQ' -- that's a capital F.A.Q. like the C in Catholic... -- which people keep referring to because it doesn't appear to be [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq/).

I just don't spend enough time on meta ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the link for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tagged questions in the [Stack Overflow faq - what about](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about) section actually

On meta, you could find faq question list on right side on homepage.