# per-site /faqs should link to the community FAQ list

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, meta, stackexchange-2.0, faq-update-request

[A year ago, someone asked:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65913)

> [The official FAQ for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) (should perhaps be renamed to include SE-2.0?) is quite informative, but there is no prominent link anywhere at parent sites.
>
> Why isn't it at least linked in the FAQ linked to at every single page?

This [was brushed off by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65947) with:

> Because I think the community FAQ as it exists today is an unreadable, un-navigable mess.

Very well, but that's no longer the case.

[More recently, someone else asked:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96780)

> Could you add a link to the Community Faq to the faq?

This [was answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96784) in a very SO-specific way:

> You can find the link for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tagged questions in the [Stack Overflow faq - what about](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about) section actually

(And the answer was accepted.) While that answer is applicable to SO, it has no application to the various SE2.0 sites. They link (in their own /faq pages) to their own metas' `faq`-tagged questions, but do not link to MSO's.

So at the risk of beating a dead horse, I'll ask again:

**Can each site's `/faq#what-about` please link to ["FAQ for Stack Exchange sites"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931)?** It's a valuable resource for users of all sites, with information not anywhere else coherent.

Comment: As these new sites splinter off more from the community that actually knows what MSO _is_, this could be helpful.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the community FAQ _is_ still an unreadable, un-navigable mess.

Comment: @PopularDemand, it's really not. I go to that page, search in my browser for `delet`, and I get exactly what I'm looking for. Same for `comment` (second search result), etc. But even if it _is_ unreadable and unnavigable, a link to it is still better than none.